# Can Greasemonkey keep script data and connections alive on a new page or reload?

Tags: javascript, persistence, greasemonkey

I'm trying to make a script that adds a chat to a webpage. I'm running the chat through a `node.js` server with `socket.IO`.

The chat works, but my problem is:

On reload or when I change a page the old connection(session) and data are lost and the script starts fresh on the new page.
This takes time to set the connection up and transfer past data(chat log) each time a new page is opened.

I was wondering if it is possible to keep the connection and data between reloads (page changes). In other words to keep the chat "unaffected" when the page changes.

Comment: No. Greasemonkey executes its scripts in the context of the page being viewed. If the user navigates away from that page or reloads it, the connection will be severed. It should be possible to save chat data to a cookie or local storage, but you will have to reopen the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing [**details**](http://sscce.org/), we can only answer in general terms.

So, yes, Greasemonkey can preserve sessions.

1. Use cookies to preserve session state with your server.  Note that [`GM_xmlhttpRequest()`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) sends the same cookies that a normal Firefox request would.
2. Rather than fetch the chat history from the server, you can keep it on the local drive using [`localStorage`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/local-storage/info).